# shiny DT _row_last_clicked

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am having an issue with the _row_last_clicked option provided for tables created in shiny interfaces with the rstudio DT library. I am trying to select a row in a datatable, make modifications to it and output it to the shiny ui.r. It works for the first-time selection, but when I again click on the same table row which I just selected previously, the _row_last_clicked seems to remain unresponsive (=NULL?). Here is a mininmal example (ui.r likely irrelevant) of what I am trying to achieve:

```
# server.r-side:

table_x<-# ... loads the dataframe
redo_cal<-reactiveValues()  
redo_cal$a<-1

observe({ 
    redo_cal$a
    output$some_table <- DT::renderDataTable(           
        table_x,
        server = TRUE, # same problem with FALSE
        selection =c('single')
    )
})


observeEvent(
    input$some_table_row_last_clicked,{
    s<-input$some_table_row_last_clicked
    table_x[s,]<- # some reversible modifications based on the row selection ...
    redo_cal$a<-(redo_cal$a+1) # trigger above renderDataTable
})
```

The issue persists for both the latest github version of DT as well as the release found on CRAN. I have read several related posts but couldn`t figure out a satisfying solution. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: it s scope issue you need to have table_x as reactiveValue  ( my mind)

Comment: thanks! just tried your suggestion - but the problem of not being able to select the same ui table row twice consecutively persists.

Comment: so you need  `some_table_row_selected` insted `row_clicked`

Comment: thank you. its some_table_rows_selected; but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you right you need `some_table_row_selected`
and `table_x`(`dd$d` - in my example) be `reactiveValues`

See example where
 `# some reversible modifications based on the row selection` == `log` of x
Every time you select row value of x in this row `log`-ed

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data=data.frame(x=1:10,y=2:11)

ui=shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("tt")
  )
)


server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  dd=reactiveValues(d=data)
  output$tt=DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(
      dd$d,selection =c('single')
    )
    
    
  )
  observeEvent(input$tt_rows_selected,{
    
    dd$d[input$tt_rows_selected,1]<-log(dd$d[input$tt_rows_selected,1])
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

In each session your data refreshed

## PS

Best minimal example its something which anyone can copy\paste and test.

Comment: Amazing, that works! I think I got the point; the observeEvent _rows_selected triggers the re-execution of the dd$d renderDataTable; this in turn resets the _rows_selected; which thus stay at a single entry. In my initial example, this was not re-executed. Thanks very much, this drove me nuts ...